# ImageResizer Pipeline_AuthorizeImage for all image requests (even ones without resize commands)

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

Images in certain folders need to have additional authorization performed on them.  I have it working for image requests made with resize commands (i.e. /images/image.jpg?width=500), but requests to the main image itself do not trigger authorization (i.e. a request to /images/image.jpg).

Is there a configuration option available to make ImageResizer fire the Pipeline_AuthorizeImage event on *all* image requests?

**My Resizer Config**

```
  <resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="DiskCache"/>
      <add name="AutoRotate"/>
      <add name="SimpleFilters"/>
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
```

Edit, based on the accepted answer below, here's how I did it:

**Global ASAX**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite += Pipeline_Rewrite;
}

void Pipeline_Rewrite(IHttpModule sender, HttpContext context, IUrlEventArgs e)
{
    if(isProtectedFolder(context))
    {
       //default to safe option
       context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
       var allowAccess = false;

       //check stuff......

       if (!allowAccess)
       {
          context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
          context.Response.End();
          return;
       }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Config.Pipeline.PostAuthorizeRequestStart` if you want to intercept *all* HTTP requests, or `Config.Pipeline.Rewrite` if you want to intercept all *image* requests.

Comment: That did it, thanks.  I added a code sample to my original post above to indicate how I implemented it.